# Почему в javascript нельзя писать условия if через "a === (b || c)"

Tags: javascript

В общем заголовок вопроса полностью исчерпывающий. Просто хочу понять, почему в javascript нельзя писать условия if через "a === (b || c)", типа:

```
var a = 2,
    b = 2,
    c = 3;

if (a === (b || c)) {
  console.log(a)
}

return null
```

Или иначе, если это не реализуемо:

- как можно записать более лаконичную версию `if (a === b || b === c)`

Comment: почему в русском языке нельзя назвать стол стулом?

Comment: @Igor петросян... Аргументировать можно?

Comment: потому что сначала выполняется операция в скобках

Comment: @Igor спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Куда уж более лаконичней..

Comment: @Igor, Тогда уж в математике, раз вопрос в приоритете операций.

Comment: А почему нельзя? Очень даже можно, пишите на здоровье!

Comment: @Other сначала выполняется операция в математике? или в математике нельзя назвать стол?

Comment: @Igor, В математике можно, но не уверен что после всяких преобразований Лоренца это будет всё ещё стол :)

Comment: Если таких условий много, то можно так ([1,3,4,2,7].indexOf(4) > -1)

Comment: @Kain тогда уж `[1,3,4,2,7].includes(4)`

Answer (score 0):

Писать условие `a === b || b === c` как `b === (a || c)` нельзя по той простой причине что эти выражения не эквивалентны. В Javascript операции выполняются не в том порядке в котором они "выполняются" в русском языке, а в соответствии с фиксированными приоритетами и довольно простой грамматикой. Конкретно в выражении `b === (a || c)` сначала вычисляется `a || c` - в результате чего получается одно число, с которым и сравнивается `b`. Для того чтобы сравнить `b` с двумя числами, надо выполнить два сравнения.

Вообще, условие `a === b || b === c` по своей форме довольно простое и нет смысла пытаться упрощать его.

Но если по какой-то причине дублировать `b` нежелательно (например, пишется Write-Only однострочник) - можно использовать массив и метод [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes): `[a, c].includes(b)`

Answer (score -2):

```js
let test = (a, b, c) => {
  return (a === (b || c));
}

console.info(test(2, 2, 3));
console.info(test(2, 2));
console.info(test(2, undefined, 3));
```

Comment: Зачем вы используете HTML-разметку? Они все только усложняет. Можно же использовать вызов console.log...

Comment: Не все знают что делает "console.log('')"

Comment: Как будто все знают английский язык - но это не помешало вам написать сообщения на английском.

Comment: Да и getElementsByTagName - тоже не самая известная функция.

Comment: смотря для кого